# How to send binary data over JSON object which I've got by reading PDF file?

Tags: php, json, pdf, postman, pdf-reader

I'm reading a PDF file content using php fread function. Now I want to post this data through JSON object. So, how can I send this data(content of PDF file)?

I'm using POSTMAN to send pdf file by selecting binary in header option and getting desired result. But how can I achieve this programatically using PHP.

```
$readfile = fopen("newfile.pdf", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
echo fread($readfile,filesize("newfile.pdf"));
fclose($readfile);
```

Using this fread method I'm getting content of 'newfile.pdf'.

I want to send content of 'newfile.pdf' as a JSON object without base64 encode or decode.

Comment: You want to use a plain text data format (JSON) to send binary data (PDF) avoiding text-to-binary encoding (Base64). That's simply not possible. Perhaps you want to use the same format as Postman, which I bet is not JSON (not at least for the binary part).